# Prevent wrapping <span> tags for ASP.NET server control

Tags: asp.net, servercontrols

I am writing various ASP.NET Server controls and am needing to remove the  tags that wrap my control by default. I am aware that you can change the tag to a different tag (as in this question, [How Do I Change the render behavior of my custom control from being a span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084311/how-do-i-change-the-render-behavior-of-my-custom-control-from-being-a-span)) but how can you prevent it?

I am inheriting from WebControl (can also inherit from CompositeControl).

I typically get:

```
<span>Control output</span>
```

I need:

```
Control output
```

I am overriding RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output) and the CreateChildControls() methods (across various controls). My immediate need is to address the issue using the RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output) method.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What about this?

```
    public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("");
    }

    public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("");
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant solution :) I actually used an empty method for both and just put a comment line explaining why they are there. Not sure if that is any different than yours but having it write a blank string seems unnecessary.

Comment: This helped me a lot - had to read a lot of 'good tips', before I found your perfect solution. Would give you more than one upvote if possible *g*

Comment: I'm trying to remove the span surrounding a System.Web.UI.Web.Controls.Checkbox. This works if I inherit from that class, however, the CssClass value doesn't get applied to the rendered CheckBox control. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4):

A more elegant way to do this is by using the contrustor of WebControl (By default this is called with the HtmlTextWriterTag.Span)

```
public MyWebControl() : base(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div){}
```

and override the RenderBeginTag method to add custom attributes or other stuff:

```
public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute("class", "SomeClassName");
        base.RenderBeginTag(writer);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. While this will allow you to change the span to a different element, such as the div given in your example, it doesn't allow you to remove the outer element completely, as requested. You could pass in `HtmlTextWriterTag.Unknown` or an empty string to the call to `base()`, but while that removes the name of the element, the angle brackets for the element are still kept, so you end up with the invalid markup: `<>`.

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing the same issue.  In my case I was overriding the methods:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    { /* Insert the control's stylesheet on the page */ }
```

and

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        { /* Control rendering here, <span> tag will show up */ }
```

To prevent this, I simply replaced the `RenderContents` override with the following:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
        { /* Control rendering, no <span> tag */ }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using Render instead of RenderContents works for me. This way the RenderBeginTag/RenderEndTag is never actually called

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the accepted answer is entirely necessary. I could be wrong, but the render method calls all three:

- RenderBeginTag
- RenderContents
- RenderEndTag

So you should be able to just override render and manually call RenderContents:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{ 
    this.RenderContents(writer);
}
```

Anyone? Maybe I'm missing something. I know this thread is old but I ran into this recently that the above was my solution.